# How do I prevent the Sleep button from locking the screen

Tags: 11.10, shortcut-keys, lock-screen

My keyboard has a Sleep button. I defined a shortcut in System Settings, Keyboard > Shortcuts > own settings (or similar), so that the Sleep buttons runs a script. That works.

But since my upgrade to Oneiric, something also locks the screen (in the same way the screen is locked when I press Ctrl+Alt+L). Can I disable that behaviour? What's the name of that lock screen?

I tried hiding gnome-screensaver and /etc/acpi/ and I looked in gconf-editor /apps/gnome-power-manager/buttons. I didn't find anything related in dconf-editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remap the key using `~/.Xmodmap`. Use `xev` (in a terminal) to find the offending keycode, then assign a different keysym, e.g. XF86WakeUp. Append this line to `~/.Xmodmap` (create that file if it does not yet exist):

```
keycode 150 = XF86WakeUp
```

After logging out and logging in again your key should be mapped. If you don't want to log out, you can also use `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` to reload the key mappings.

Using `xev` to actually find the keycode of the key that you want to remap might be not so easy: if the key is already bound to an action (e.g. in the Gnome keyboard properties), `xev` does not show the keycode. As an example, this is the kind of `xev` output that you want to see:

```
KeyPress event, serial 41, synthetic NO, window 0x5800001,
    root 0xb3, subw 0x0, time 312883, (737,182), root:(946,647),
    state 0x0, keycode 180 (keysym 0x1008ff18, XF86HomePage), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

You can see the keycode (180) in the third line after the word "keycode". If you don't get such a block that starts with "KeyPress event", your key probably is already bound. You can try to use a non-Gnome desktop like LXDE or KDE and use `xev` there.

Comment: Can you explain this further. *(Trying to learn)*

Comment: I edited the answer. Is that what you were looking for?