# XF86WakeUp keys - where do they come from?

Tags: 12.04, emacs, shortcut-keys

```
$ head -1 /etc/issue && emacs --version | head -1
Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS \n \l
GNU Emacs 23.3.1
```

From time to time I get undefined messages in the echo area (that do not show up in buffer `*Messages*`) about XF86WakeUp. In fact, I <kbd>C-h l</kbd>ed to see that there are 22 such `<XF86WakeUp>` keys in a row.

Reading [How do I prevent the Sleep button from locking the screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104196/how-do-i-prevent-the-sleep-button-from-locking-the-screen/151460#151460)

I figured out that the blue <kbd>Fn</kbd>-key left to Ctrl does this.

On the other hand, that very same key is needed to enable the Soundoff meaning of Esc, and similar for F1-F12. Just to make this clear: Emacs gets Esc directly. Thus, Esc does not mean Soundoff within Emacs. But Fn-Esc does.

So what is the clean way to fix this without affecting the other <kbd>Fn</kbd> keycombinations within Emacs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is solved most probably due to a recent update of 12.04.